# Ionic 2 webview websocket is not working in android

Tags: cordova, angular, websocket, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Ionic 2 webview for app development. I am trying to create open websocket connection using

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com");
```

It opens up a connection successfully in ios but **403 forbidden in android.**
While debugging I came to know that **cookies were not passed** as part of request header during handshake. Also origin header has **http:// for ios** and **file:// for android.**
Code part is exactly same for both platforms.

> Note: Tested in android **6.0 and 5.0**

Comment: Did you whitelist the domain?

Comment: I think yes. access origin=* in config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the origin as "http://" I am able to establish a connection and consume messages. I used this [websocket plugin](https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android) and provided **plugin options** as mentioned in the document. But the server should also allow **file://** origin I guess.